# Use each element of var to make a http request in Mule

Tags: variables, foreach, scope, payload, mule4

I have a collection of `matches` saved to a var. Each `match` has a `gameId`. I want to use this `gameId` to make an API call.
I set up a for each scope using `matches` with a `counter` var.

```
<set-variable value="#[payload]" doc:name="Set Matches" doc:id="bb1093b0-3dd9-4515-8f42-dd496f00477b" variableName="matches"/>
<set-variable value="#[[]]" doc:name="Deaths" doc:id="a7341e19-07f8-418d-b39a-5bc415e75fba" variableName="deaths"/>
<foreach doc:name="For each match" doc:id="506fa944-d46f-4684-9c75-73088265ca80" collection="vars.matches" rootMessageVariableName="matches">
    <http:request method="GET" doc:name="GetTimeline" doc:id="63708489-4d10-4e79-b5aa-c8fc723e80c6" config-ref="HTTP_Request_configuration" path="/match/v4/timelines/by-match/{matchId}">
        <http:uri-params ><![CDATA[#[output application/java
---
{
    "matchId" : vars.matches[vars.counter + 1].gameId
}]]]></http:uri-params>
    </http:request>
    <ee:transform doc:name="MapDeaths" doc:id="a6e22968-2229-4574-8cae-44225013b9cf">
        <ee:message>
            <ee:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
    frames: payload.frames map ( frame , indexOfFrame ) -> {
        events: frame.events map ( event , indexOfEvent ) -> vars.deaths + event
    }
}]]></ee:set-payload>
        </ee:message>
    </ee:transform>
</foreach>
```

Yet `matchId` from `"matchId" : vars.matches[vars.counter + 1].gameId` always evalutes to null. What am I missing there?
Edit:
I'm using Mule 4.2 and the json structure of matches looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "matches": [
      {
        "key": "val",
        "key": val,
        ...
      },
      {
        "key": "val",
        "key": val,
        ...
      },
      ...
```

Comment: which version Mule you are on, suggests 3.8 ?

Comment: It is Mule 4.x from what I see in the flow (DataWeave 2.0, vars). 
@Peter. please clarify what is the type or object in payload that is assigned to vars.matches.

Comment: @Ven I'm using version 4.2

Comment: Did you tried setting `{matchId}` as query parameter instead of path ?

Answer (score 1):

Set `{matchId}` as Query string parameter and define request a Target variable, use that in dataweave

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that your payload and the expression you are using doesn't match (pun not intended). The payload is an array that contains objects, with a matches attribute. The expression apparently assumes that the payload contains a matches attribute, which contains a gameId attribute. That is the reason it returns null.

Also the intention is not clear, given that you didn't show were gameId is in your example.

Let's try with a more detailed example.

For the input:

```
[
  {
    "matches": [
      {
        "keyA": "val1",
        "keyB": "val2"
      },
      {
        "keyC": "val3",
        "keyD": "val4"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The expression `payload.matches.keyA` returns `null`.

You could do `payload[0].matches[0].keyA` to obtain "val1".

This assumes there data is from the first element of the array and you want to use only one key from one of the matches. Of course if you need to iterate on the different arrays levels you will need to use map or group, but it is a different use case.